My APEX codes are returning wrong datetime?

Can anyone help me? Seems like the following line of APEX codes are returning wrong time?
I am in Malaysia timezone & the login user who is executing these line of codes is in Sydney timezone.
The lines are as below:
String dateTimeQuery = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' 
    + System.now().addHours(-12).format('yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z''); 
System.Debug('-12' + dateTimeQuery); 
String dateTimeQuery14 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' 
    + System.now().addHours(-14).format('yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z''); 
System.Debug('-14' + dateTimeQuery14); 
String dateTimeQuery16 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' 
    + System.now().addHours(-16).format('yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z''); 
System.Debug('-16' + dateTimeQuery16); 
String dateTimeQuery20 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' 
    + System.now().addHours(-20).format('yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z''); 
System.Debug('-20' + dateTimeQuery20);

UPDATE


You put a literal 'Z' into the date format string, so it deceived you. Simply changing it to use the Z format will tell you a different story:
String dateTimeQuery = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-12).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-12' + dateTimeQuery);
String dateTimeQuery14 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-14).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-14' + dateTimeQuery14);
String dateTimeQuery16 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-16).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-16' + dateTimeQuery16);
String dateTimeQuery20 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-20).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-20' + dateTimeQuery20);

Outputs (in my case, Denver/America):
16:11:42:002 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|-12 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T04:11:42-0600
16:11:42:002 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|-14 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T02:11:42-0600
16:11:42:002 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|-16 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T12:11:42-0600
16:11:42:002 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|-20 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-20T08:11:42-0600

To get the values you're apparently expecting, you want to format as GMT:
String dateTimeQuery = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-12).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-12' + dateTimeQuery);
String dateTimeQuery14 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-14).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-14' + dateTimeQuery14);
String dateTimeQuery16 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-16).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-16' + dateTimeQuery16);
String dateTimeQuery20 = ' WHERE LastModifiedDate >= ' + System.now().addHours(-20).formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ');
System.debug('-20' + dateTimeQuery20);

Which outputs:
16:15:08:002 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|-12 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T10:15:08+0000
16:15:08:002 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|-14 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T08:15:08+0000
16:15:08:002 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|-16 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T06:15:08+0000
16:15:08:002 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|-20 WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-05-21T02:15:08+0000


Hi thank you. I am expecting Sydney timezone for now. But I might use GMT later. I just want to get the calculation right. I tried your advice to use z format and got the following result (refer updated image in my post)? Kindly advise
